# Is there a way to open a link in a frame and suppress all popups on the external site?

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering if it's possible to open a link to another site, in a frame (or by some other means), and suppress the 1-2 popups that load on the external site.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is an easy way to accomplish this. Your best bet would be to have a page on your server act as a proxy for fetching the page from the other site, then modify the html you get back to remove pop ups. Not an easy task, but possible. As a POC, you could explicitly target the popups you know about by looking for the page url they open.

Comment: Yah that's what I figured, unfortunately, thats not an option.

Comment: Because I need to actually link to the external site, otherwise it defeats the whole purpose.